# Small HighCharts disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want this highchart - http://jsfiddle.net/zPDca/ inside a popup. But if i decrease its width   to lets say to 200 px, it dissapers. Any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like 251 px is the lower limit for the width.
This was probably a decision the developers made due to readability. Think about it:
This is a stock chart and it contains the "detail" view and a navigator view, you have export enabled and by default you are showing the buttons, the default selection buttons for zooming are also shown. Wouldn't this be really crowded for the user? Why not use a different kind of chart (standard highchart maybe) that shows latest data and gives user option to expand view. This would save a lot of space in the view.
Things you can try:
Remove the export buttons (you can write your own extension to still do exporting without useing the built-in buttons)
Remove the "Zoom" text
Change chart to be less "busy" overall

Having a data visualization is all about quickly seeing the data you need - not necessarily seeing all the options you may need in a tight space. If this chart is to be used for continuous monitoring you can strip it of all option settings but have it use the options set by the user in a "primary/setup" chart.

Answer (score 1):

Look this example http://jsfiddle.net/zPDca/1/ 
It's working well.

If you take a look the [reference](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#chart--width) you can see that it can be calculated by the containing element. So you just have to remove `width` from your chart as you can see on my example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got the answer. Versions higher than 1.1.5 do not allow charts smaller than certain dimension. I do not know why. But I'm detouring right now by using version 1.1.5.